# How to know pixel values precisely?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pixels

How to know one single pixel RGB and transparency values precisely in Photoshop? Using eyedropper tools I seem not to be able to do that, i.e. it shows RGB=(0,0,0) on partially transparent pixels ("all layers" is selected in options).

My image has layer options like shadows and glowing and transparent areas.

**EDIT 1**

Probably the reason is because I use layer effects?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the Eyedropper tool to Point Sample, and Sample All Layers:

[image]

Then set the Info panel to show RGB on one side and Opacity on the other:
 (this is done by clicking the icon in each section to open a menu)

[image]

Comment: Hm, it does not work for me. It still shows zeros over shadow.

Comment: @Suzan can you see the checkerboard background behind the shadow, or is there some kind of fill?

Comment: Yes I see checker board

Comment: @Suzan could you upload a small sample file where you're having this problem?  It is working for me; I would like to confirm that it works for me on your file.

Comment: Here it is: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B1jZw9H7L4gmLUZxV00tbWJJX1U

Comment: @Suzan thanks to the file and your updated question I think I understand now.  Photoshop is correct to display `(0,0,0)` at that point, as that is your Drop Shadow color.  If you change the Drop Shadow color to red for example, you should see `(255,0,0)`.  Presumably however you want different information.  The Opacity field as shown in my answer above will give you the density of the shadow.  If you want a composite color, you will need to provide some background to composite with (perhaps a solid white fill).

Comment: @Suzan glad I could help.